bad tree block start
Due to a power outage, my btrfs disk no longer mounts.
mount says can't read superblock on /dev/sdb1
dmesg says
[ 3543.386998] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bad tree block start, mirror 1 want 762062323712 have 0
[ 3543.399692] BTRFS error (device sdb1): bad tree block start, mirror 2 want 762062323712 have 0

btrfs check says
checksum verify failed on 762062323712 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 762062323712 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 762062323712 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
bad tree block 762062323712, bytenr mismatch, want=762062323712, have=0
ERROR: failed to read block groups: Input/output error
ERROR: cannot open file system

Things that didn't help:

btrfs check --repair -> same output as btrfs check
btrfs rescue super-recover -> says All supers are valid, no need to recover

Things that helped:

btrfs restore -> starts copying...
mount with -o rescue=ignorebadroots,ro -> mounts everything properly, read-only

So it seems the disk has no bad sectors, it's only a checksum problem.
How do I recompute the checksums to make btrfs happy? Is it btrfs rescue chunk-recover?
